# SQL Query - Find The Highest Number

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

Could someone please help me? I need to find this query, but I cannot get them to display as one. I know I wrote it wrong but not sure how to correct it. I need it to only display the customer who booked the longest period.

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.CHECKIN_DATE, ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.NIGHTS
FROM   CUSTOMERS, ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS
WHERE  CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_ID
SELECT MAX(Nights) AS NIGHTS
FROM ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS, CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: @P.Salmon, how did you edit it to display like that?

Comment: A take tour,read instructions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks B highlight code block and ctrl+k.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired result:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.CHECKIN_DATE, ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.NIGHTS
FROM CUSTOMERS
JOIN ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS
ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS.NIGHTS = (
    SELECT MAX(NIGHTS) AS NIGHTS
    FROM ACCOMMODATION_BOOKINGS
);
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, so I had to use a join statement?

Comment: It's better to convert WHERE IN to JOIN too.

Comment: You can just use `=` operator instead of `IN` as inner query would return only one value.

Comment: @JitendraYadav replaced `IN` by `=`